# Converting my jQuery Mobile website to a native app

Tags: jquery, mobile, native

I've developed a mobile website using jQuery Mobile and I want to convert it to a native application (Android but if iOS is possible too than even better).
My mobile website has HTML, JavaScript and PHP to connect to the database and uses MySQL queries.

What are my possibilities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PhoneGap is a free and open source framework that allows you to create mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the platforms you care about.Download the **[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/download/)**.

please follow the this **[link](https://build.phonegap.com/)** to know more .

Answer (score 3):

Well there is plenty of options... I have sorted them according to popularity,  even though most people don't know any other one that PhoneGap.

### 1 - [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) :

> PhoneGap is a free and open source framework that allows you to create
>   mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the platforms you care
>   about.

### 2 - [Corona](http://coronalabs.com) :

> Corona SDK builds rich mobile apps for iOS, Android, Kindle and Nook. Build high quality mobile apps in a fraction of the time.

### 3 - [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) :

> Appcelerator is the only mobile first platform that enables enterprise to create, deliver and analyze their mobile applications.